# Find who is using outdated TLS for SMTP traffic

Tags: powershell, ssl, exchange-server

I'm trying to collect information from the Exchange protocol logs to identify systems using outdated TLS 1.0 before upgrading from 2016 to Exchange 2019.  I am able to use get-childitem and select-string to search the smtpreceive log files for the SP_PROT_TLS1_0_SERVER string, however what I would ultimately like to do would be to search the Exchange smtpreceive transport logs for the string SP_PROT_TLS1_0_SERVER.  From the hits for SP_PROT_TLS1_0_SERVER, I would like to use the session-id to collect EHLO and MAIL FROM information and record all three values in a csv file so they can be verified in the transport logs for accuracy.  So far I've tried to load all fields of the smtpreceive files into a variable, but something's not right and I'm not getting any output.

Comment: Show what you have, along with a short sample of the data.

Comment: I am able to use logparser to get the session-id from the logs, but I'm lost on how to use those values to return the ehlo and mail from lines.  '.\logparser.exe -i:csv -q:on -nskiplines:4 "SELECT DISTINCT session-id FROM 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\TransportRoles\Logs\FrontEnd\ProtocolLog\SmtpReceive\*.log' WHERE context LIKE '%TLS protocol SP_PROT_TLS1_0_SERVER%'"' gives me the session-id as 08D9A473F614FB0B
08D9A473F614FB12
08D9A473F614FBE1
08D9A473F614FBED.  I've tried using variables, however they only return one line for each session-id.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to trawl through Exchange Protocol Logs Scanning for sent and received traffic (Mail Flow via SMTP Logging)

**Exchange Server TLS guidance Part 2: Enabling TLS 1.2 and Identifying Clients Not Using It**https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/exchange-server-tls-guidance-part-2-enabling-tls-1-2-and/ba-p/607761

**Exchange Server: Search message tracking logs** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/search-message-tracking-logs?view=exchserver-2019

**Analyzing the protocol logs and Message tracking logs in Exchange 2013** https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23182.analyzing-the-protocol-logs-and-message-tracking-logs-in-exchange-2013.aspx

**Example entries from Exchange Server 2010**

A server **sending** mail to another system using TLS 1.2:

```
2018-02-22T13:53:10.494Z,<CONNECTORNAME>,08D578EB9C3F6C39,28,10.0.0.240:15443,192.168.1.42:25,*,,"TLS protocol SP_PROT_TLS1_2_CLIENT negotiation succeeded using bulk encryption algorithm CALG_AES_256 with strength 256 bits, MAC hash algorithm CALG_SHA_384 with strength 384 bits and key exchange algorithm CALG_ECDHE with strength 384 bits"
```

A server **receiving** mail from another system using TLS 1.2

```
2018-02-22T13:50:37.681Z,SERVERNAME\CONNECTORNAME Internet,07C578BB0E912319,22,10.0.0.241:25,192.168.1.102:63767,*,,"TLS protocol SP_PROT_TLS1_2_SERVER negotiation succeeded using bulk encryption algorithm CALG_AES_256 with strength 256 bits, MAC hash algorithm CALG_SHA_384 with strength 384 bits and key exchange algorithm CALG_ECDHE with strength 256 bits"
```

**SMTP Log Parsing Script WebSites**

https://scriptolog.blogspot.com/2007/08/smtp-log-parsing.html

https://www.axigen.com/community/t/made-a-powershell-script-to-parse-smtp-receiving-log/512

Comment: So far, I've been able to do the following with the help of the links you provided.  I use the unique session ID as the constant identifier between 3 files.  We have a loadbalancer and it doesn't show the client IP, we need to collect the session-ID for the TLS1.0 messages, then collect the Mail From field, and also the EHLO command.  Logparser functions, by finding just what is specified in the WHERE <field> LIKE "whatever" statement and discards others.  That makes it impossible to use this to grab the session-ID from the TLS line, then use that to search the for rest of the information.